# Does this code show a bug in Swift or am I doing something wrong

Tags: swift

```
Protocol EnemyView {
    var face: SKTexture! {get set}
}

class VectorEnemyImageMaker {

    func createImage(enemySprite: EnemyView, face: Int) {

        // ...
        enemySprite.face = SKTexture(image: image)
        // ...
    }
}
```

gets me a "Cannot assign to 'face' in enemySprite

here is the strange thing. If I change the class to:

```
class VectorEnemyImageMaker {

    func createImage(enemySprite: EnemySprite, face: Int) {

        // ...
        var e = enemySprite as EnemyView
        e.face = SKTexture(image: image)
        // ...
    }
}
```

this works!

Does anyone have the solution to this or is this a bug in Swift?

Comment: what is `EnemySprite`? Is protocol or class? and please clean relation of `EnemySprite` and `EnemyView `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func createImage(enemySprite: EnemyView, face: Int) {
    var e = enemySprite as EnemyView
    e.face = SKTexture(image: image)
```

The above compiles, but this does not:

```
func createImage(enemySprite: EnemyView, face: Int) {
    enemySprite.face = SKTexture(image: image)
```

... because Swift does not know that the `EnemyView` adopter, the type of `enemySprite`, is a class. It might be a struct (or an enum). And you cannot mutate a struct instance (or an enum instance) in place; a struct (or enum) is a value type, not a reference type. So you have to have a `var` reference to the instance in order to mutate a property of it.

You can simply guarantee to Swift that only a class will adopt EnemyView, when you declare it, like this:

```
Protocol EnemyView : class { // only classes can adopt me
    var face: SKTexture! {get set}
}
```

Another approach is to make the parameter itself a `var` reference, so that it can be mutated:

```
func createImage(var enemySprite: EnemyView, face: Int) { // note "var"
    enemySprite.face = SKTexture(image: image)
```

Comment: And see my Swift tutorial if you don't understand the difference between value types and reference types: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECreferenceTypes That section talks directly about the difference in the way value types cannot be mutated in place and reference types can.